# How can I implement tap-able Text widget, Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a Text widget on pressing which another Route has to be shown. But I could not see any onPressed() method for the Text widget. Please Help.

Answer (score 1):

In your case there are multiple routes where you can go.

1. Using material TextButton:

   `TextButton(onPressed: () {}, child: Text('Your child'))`
2. Using InkWell Widget, which covers your widget with 'as button' properties, splashes etc, which allows you to have more customisable buttons taps:

   `InkWell(onTap: () {}, onDoubleTap: () {}, onLongPress: () {}, onHover: () {},  ..etc , child: Text('Your child widget'))`
3. Using GestureDetector, is the most customisable solution for any gestures you can provide (from its name), can handle taps, long presses, double taps, drags etc.
   Syntax is similar:

   `GestureDetector(onTap: () {}, child: Text('Your child widget'))`

Answer (score 0):

Try using TextButton widget:

```
TextButton(
            onPressed: () {},
            child: Text('Simple Button'),
          ),
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way to make any widget tappable is to use `GestrureDetector` you just put it outside of the widget/widgets you want and you can use [dozen of properties](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/GestureDetector-class.html).
For example

```
GestureDetector(child:

 onPressed: () {},

 Text('Your text')

)
```